# KeyError in python

Tags: python, bigdata

I am trying to count the  number of times each string in my list is repeated but it keeps giving me KeyError:

```
def gono(l):
    f={}
    for h in l:
        if(f.get(f[h])):
            f[h] += 1
        else:
            f[h]=1
    return f
```

```
Error content :
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e02904625299> in <module>
     23             f[h]=1
     24     return f
---> 25 v=gono(h)
     26 v
     27 

<ipython-input-68-e02904625299> in gono(l)
     18     f={}
     19     for h in l:
---> 20         if(f.get(f[h])):
     21             f[h] += 1
     22         else:

KeyError: 'CLOSED'
```

The list is :
['CLOSED',
 'PENDING_PAYMENT',
 'COMPLETE',
 'CLOSED',
 'COMPLETE',
 'COMPLETE',
 'COMPLETE',
 'PROCESSING',
 'PENDING_PAYMENT',
 'PENDING_PAYMENT']

Comment: You need to specify a key in `get`, not value! Your code is fixed with `f.get(f[h])` -> `f.get(h)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
def gono(l):
    return Counter(l)
```

Example result:

```
>>> gono(['CLOSED', 'PENDING_PAYMENT', 'COMPLETE', 'CLOSED', 'COMPLETE', 'COMPLETE', 'COMPLETE', 'PROCESSING', 'PENDING_PAYMENT', 'PENDING_PAYMENT'])
Counter({'COMPLETE': 4, 'PENDING_PAYMENT': 3, 'CLOSED': 2, 'PROCESSING': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question doesn't belong to "data science", this is more of a python coding question. Anyways it seems like dictionary is empty when you call the function first. How you can call f[h] without getting a key error in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
mylist= ['CLOSED', 'PENDING_PAYMENT', 'COMPLETE', 'CLOSED', 'COMPLETE', 'COMPLETE', 'COMPLETE', 'PROCESSING', 'PENDING_PAYMENT', 'PENDING_PAYMENT']
mylist.count("CLOSED")
```